# SPList query result different from SPList column display

Tags: splist, spquery

I'm doing an `SPQuery` on the `'Modified By'` (Editor) column of a `SPList`.

While my SharePoint list displays names like `#Doe, John`, my query result for this column is `1;#Doe John`. Where does the `1;` come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the default SharePoint behavior.

When you get any user value field from the list, it will return always in this format: `1;#Doe John`

where `;#` is the delimiter to separate the username which is `Doe John` and `1` is the ID of the username for that site.

Look at the below code for example:

```
SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, item["Editor"].ToString());
SPUser author = userValue.User;
```

Above code gets the whole value (`1:#Doe John`) in `SPFieldUserValue` object and parse the value to get other details of the user like login name, email etc..

Hope this helps!